# Transit visa in Hong Kong for Pakistani

Tags: transit-visas, pakistani-citizens, hong-kong

I am travelling from Australia to Japan on a visitor visa and I am transiting through Hong Kong (4-hour layover) with Cathy Pacific Airways. Do I need a transit visa as I am a Pakistani national? TIA

Comment: The duplicate cited above is five years old. Is that answer still correct?

Comment: A comment to the duplicate indicates the answer is still valid. I voted to close.